# Tesseract ocr: How can I train my own tessdata library on batch with lots of single character image?

Tags: extract, tesseract

1. I have lots of images which only have 1 single character, how can I use them to train my own tessdata library on batch ? Is there any tips?

2.
And besides,
I'm confused with the feature extraction part between library training and character recognization ? Could anyone explained the flow ? 
Thanks very much!

Comment: Email address removed. Hactor, pls don't post your email, it's likely to end up on some spam list somewhere. You need to bookmark the question and come back periodically to check or you can mark a question when you ask it for SO to send emails when answers appear.

Answer (score 0):

If they are of same font, put them in a multi-page TIFF and conduct training on it. [jTessBoxEditor](http://vietocr.sourceforge.net/training.html) can help you with the TIFF merging and box editing.